# Chrome adding extra question mark with my localhost URL

Tags: php, google-chrome, localhost

I have installed php with apache. I can access my project with this url in local.

```
http://localhost
```

I have changed DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file to access my project. So the above works in all browsers except CHROME.

It will add extra question mark ? with the end of the url and some extra text. please see the below.

```
http://localhost/?_sm_au_=iVV75n6kWFLgSV7R
```

This is the response displayed in this page.

```
The following error was encountered:
Zero Sized Reply

Squid did not receive any data for this request
```

Please help

Comment: looking at the information you supplied, I am guessing it is something to do with Squid, not your web server setup. Try disabling squid on localhost.

Comment: yes.. Now it works fine after changed settings